# Issue with display:none for some ajax content and a javascript toggle function

Tags: javascript, css

On my website, I am trying to incorporate all of my inline styling into an external css file. I noticed on my 7 main pages I had literally hundreds of inline `style="display:none"` statements, so I thought I would shave some kB off of my files by adding a class to my external stylesheet as follows:

```
.DN {
    display:none;
}
```

On my 7 pages, replacing every inline `style="display:none"` with `class="DN"` shaved off about 5 kB total (combined for the 7 pages). However, there were a couple of places where this failed. For example, on one page the user can choose between menu options with mouse clicks by toggling between `display:none` divs (each div is set to `display:none`...except `#div1` which by default has visibility set to visible when the user goes to this page) using the following function (`toggle(layer)` is called upon each mouse click of other page elements):

```
function toggle(layer) {
    var divs = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7", "div8", "div9",    
    "div10", "div11"];
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
        document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(layer).style.display = '';
}


<div id="div1" style="visibility:visible">More HTML here</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">More HTML here</div>
//9 more display:none divs...success
```

However, when the div styling is changed to `class="DN"` (`class="DN"` replaces `style="display:none"`), the div behaves as if the `DN` class is not even there at all. I recently encountered a similar problem with some ajax-loaded content on the site.

```
<div id="div2" class="DN">More HTML here</div>
//Fail...div does not appear upon mouseclick of menu buttons
```

I thought the external css file should set the styling for all the DOM elements. As a sidenote, I checked to make sure there were no conflicting css styling elements in my external file... There are no conflicts I can see (e.g., if one of my other divs had a `visibility:visible` style in the external CSS file, etc.). Just out of curiosity, any thoughts on what could be going wrong here by setting the `class="DN"` instead of inline `style="display:none"`?

Comment: Did you take into account the fact that a properly configured server send gzipped CSS and HTML files ? It doesn't mean you shouldn't use a class but the gain on file size is probably not so important.

Comment: It sounds like your CSS is not applying properly. What you describe should work.

Comment: Can your reproduce your problem in a fiddle ? There are too much holes here.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see if the style is being applied or overridden somewhere? or the css where DN is in is even called on the page?

Comment: Open the debugger and check what styles are being applied and from where.

Comment: It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/umfL8/2/

Comment: Are you using `document.getElementById(divs[i]).className = 'DN';`  Not `class`?

Comment: I used Firebug and The Online Lint to check my JS, and checked my HTML and css using http://validator.w3.org/...no errors I can see. What other debugger tools would I use?

Comment: When you set the `document.getElementById(layer).style.display = '';` display to an empty string, the CSS is still being applied via the stylesheet. If you want to override the stylesheet, in this case, you might need to update that line to `document.getElementById(layer).style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @dward, I tried this and you are right. I had already tried replacing the empty string with 'inline' instead of 'block' and it failed really bad...'block' works.

Comment: @dward, if you can add your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `document.getElementById(layer).style.display = '';` display to an empty string, the CSS is still being applied via the stylesheet. If you want to override the stylesheet, in this case, you might need to update that line to `document.getElementById(layer).style.display = 'block';`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have more specific `display` styling applied to the divs that aren't working as expected? for example

```
<div id="div2" class="DN">More HTML here</div>
```

if you have `#div2 {display:block;}` or `#div2 {display:inline;}` in your stylesheet, adding `.DN {display:none;}` would not have any effect, whereas an inline style of `display:none;` would.  If this is the case, you can fix it with `!important`

`.DN { display:none !important; }`

Comment: No, I was really careful about this...no overriding css. Actually, the problem was the empty string....replaced with 'block' as suggested by @dward